# Measure growth in spatial directions

Tags: qgis

I want to measure the growth of different areas in spatial directions. The same as in [this article of M.S.Moeller](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVI/8-W27/moeller.pdf) on page 5 (Figure 5 and 6).

[image]

[image]

But I don't know how to build such a Wind Rose in QGIS.
Do you have any ideas?!

Comment: I forgot to say, that I have Shapefiles of an area. But I want to know how much the city grew in a special direction.

Comment: Special directions or spatial directions?

Comment: As I understand Moellers method he builds buffers around a point and splits them with lines going from the center point in some direction. This gives the fringes. You can use the multi buffer plugin to construct the buffers, digitize a quadrat with cadtools, split this manually in orthogonal and diagonal direction, and overlay both. Then overlay the result with your areas. Then make some statistics, open the dbf file in eg Excel and plot the stacked bar diagram

Answer (score 2):

**QGIS 3.2+**

It seems the hardest part is how to create the `"Wind Rose" buffers` extends toward 8 directions, at every 1 km. I think there are 400 polygons (50 x 8) displayed in Fig.5 (Moeller 2004),

From QGIS 3.2, **Create wedge buffers** and **Join attributes by field value** tools jointly made this task easy.

**[1 Preparation]**

1) A centroid point layer.

2) We need a csv file with fields described below:

- `id` (`fid`) field to link the record with the centroid point
- `azimuth` field (22.5, 67.5, ... ..., 337.5)
- `outer radius` field (1 km, 2 km, ..., 50 km)
- `inner radius` field (0 km, 1 km, ..., 49 km)

A spreadsheet software, such as Microsoft Excel, would be helpful.

[image]

3) Read the csv file as a Delimited text layer.

**[2 Join]**

Start **Join Attributes by Field Value** (`Processing toolbox > Vector general`) and join the point layer and the csv file.

Select `Create separate feature for each matching feature (one-to-many)` as the `Join type`.

By using this option, the center point will become 400 duplicated points. (...and we do not have to repeat `Copy- and Paste-features`!)

**[3 Create Wedge buffers]**

Activate **Create wedge buffers** (`Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`) and choose `Azimuth`, `Outer radius`, and `Inner radius` from the attribute fields (use pull-down menu at the right-hand side). In the meantime keep `Wedge width` at 45.0 degrees (default value).

Then <kbd>Run</kbd> the tool.

**[4 Analyze the Raster]**

There are numbers of analytical method available in this site. Perhaps `Zonal statistics` would be a good start.

[image]